# Writing individual bits into ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java

Ok, so what I want to is write bytes to a dataouptustream and send that output stream out. I can do all that fine. What I am having trouble with is how to write individual bits inside the byte, for example:

I want to write the LSB (0) as 1, and then the remaning 1-7 bits should be the value of 100. Or maybe I want the first 2 LSB (0-1) to be 3 and the remaning to be 5. This is my attempt so far (to be far I have not really tested this code yet).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream daos=new DataOutputStream(baos);
//LSB should be 0, the remaining should be the value 50
daos.writeByte(50 >>> 1);
//2 LSBs should be 2 (10) and the remaining should be 100
daos.writeByte(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(2) + Integer.toBinaryString(100)));
daos.close();
message = baos.toByteArray();
```

Am I on the right track? Is there a really simple/straightforward method to do this? I have to do quite a lot of this so I need to really understand how to manipulate these bytes to whatever I need.

Comment: You say you have not really tested your code... Why don't you start by doing exactly that? Also, do you want to work in big endian all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
byte a = 2;
byte b = 100;
byte lsb = 2;

int c = a + (b << lsb);
```

Where `lsb` is the number of LSBs you want to reserve for your first number (`a`) and the rest is available for `b`.

Of course, if you reserve 2 bits out of 8 for `a`, this means that `b` would have to use 6 bits of less (i.e. b < 64). So the example with 100 doesn't quite work because your result is no longer a byte. 100 needs 7 bits so total is 9 bits.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. And good call on the 100, that's what I get for making up examples on the fly.